# Duplicate data in database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I try to insert datagridview value and textbox simultnaeously after a button clicked but the data were duplicated in the database.

[Database duplicate image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vX4E.png)

[Datagridview display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvXrf.png)

Can anyone tell me what's the problem in my code, please?

**My code**

```
       private void btnPay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            decimal pay, balance, total;


            total = decimal.Parse(txtNetTotal.Text);

            pay = decimal.Parse(txtCash.Text);

            balance = pay - total;

            txtCash.Text = pay.ToString("0.00");
            txtBalance.Text = balance.ToString("0.00");


        try
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvOrder.Rows)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblOrder (ProductName,Quantity,ProductPrice,TotalPrice,Cash,Balance)" +
                                                "values (@ProductName,@Quantity,@ProductPrice,@TotalPrice,@Cash,@Balance)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["colProduct"].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["colQuantity"].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductPrice", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["colPrice"].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalPrice", txtTotal.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cash", txtCash.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance", txtBalance.Text.Trim());

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Here the whole code for the button event.

Comment: where is this code written and executed? may be this method is called twice!

Comment: When you debug this, how many times does this loop iterate?  Does `dgvOrder.Rows` include a row you don't expect it to?

Comment: is there two rows in your datagrid? hint- foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvOrder.Rows)

Comment: You have inserted the values of (txtTotal,txtCash,txtBalance) the values ​​of these fields do not change when you put them in the boocle ?

Comment: @MikeMiller Yes, but when I click the pay button, a new blank row will be auto inserted.

Comment: NewbieLearner, you can add !DataGridViewRow.IsNewRow to the condition if you don't want the new row to be saved. You can also check if the fields are empty prior to saving.

Comment: Before inserting data check `if(row is DataRow){}`

Comment: @David Yes, the loop iterate like twice and just take onlt the value of textbox.

Comment: @JaydipJ I dont have any idea how to code it. Can you show me how to implement that code? Sorry. Newbie here.

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments above and on the image edited into the question, your `DataGridView` has *two* rows.  Which is why this loop is inserting *two* rows into the database:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvOrder.Rows)
```

It looks like the second row is a blank one, which explains why the second database entry has only the static values and not the row-based values.  To prevent this, you should be able to add a simple conditional:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvOrder.Rows)
{
    if (!row.IsNewRow)
    {
        // insert into the database
    }
}
```

Or, if nested code blocks are unsightly:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvOrder.Rows)
{
    if (row.IsNewRow)
        continue;
    // insert into the database
}
```

Comment: this code do the trick. Thanks :D. No duplicate data now in database.